# Same css is not working in firefox but perfect in chrome

Tags: php, css, html, google-chrome, firefox

In chrome, the image is aligned perfectly in the middle but in firefox something seems to be not working, the image seems to sticking to the top for some reason 
 and I couldn't find out the exact issue. I am attaching two images for both chrome[image: chrome image] and firefox[image]

```
<div class="img-wrap">
      <a acttype="visitstore" class="displayinlineblock action-btn deal-prod-img">
        <span class="" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;height: 100%;"></span>
        <img src="https://d1oj69lo91yuwm.cloudfront.net/store/thumb1/bigbasket.png" alt="naturesbasket">
      </a>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.img-wrap {
    height: 145px;
    min-width: 138px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.product-wrapper .img-wrap>a {
    float: left !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.deal-prod-img {
    display: inline-table !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.img-wrap>a>img {
    max-height: 133px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to vertically center the image inside it's container?

Centering things are never as intuitive as they should be, so if I were you, I would bookmark [this handy guide to centering things](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/), and refer to it anytime you need to do so.

Anyways, here are a couple of options it mentions that you could do to get a more consistent result across browsers.

You could simply give the image even padding on each side.

Or, if you make the image the only thing inside the container, then you can set the line-height to be the same as the actual height, and the image will center itself.

If it's something more complicated than that, then check out that link. You're sure to find something useful there, but I was able to get the image centered using line-height with the source code you provided.